# How should I correctly learn GNU assembly?

Tags: assembly, att, gnu-assembler

I'm learning assembly in ubuntu recently, I found some of assembles, like NASM, MASM, and GAS. Their syntax is different(particularly pseudo-directives), NASM and MASM support Intel syntax, GAS support AT&T Syntax.

Now, I want learn AT&T assembly, so, I use the GAS assemble and I found a series of about GAS manual, but it's painful to read for me, like **lack of specific examples or just simply introducing basic syntax**.

I found representative partial "guides":

- https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as.html
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GNU_assembly_syntax
- [GCC's assembly output of an empty program on x86, win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317081/gccs-assembly-output-of-an-empty-program-on-x86-win32)
- https://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs421/papers/x86-asm/asm.html

Like this example https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as.html#Scl, I want to know what `storage-class value` we have? `gccs-assembly-output-of-an-empty-program-on-x86-win32` tell me that `.scl 2` means external storage class, but I can't find anything else about this value. and so on.

Maybe I am wrong in learning direction, or I found information wrong way. So I want to ask you that have some of guide or manual about AT&T with examples and clear explanation for beginner.

I am confusing that pseudo-directives, what is it like the standard assembly program structure?

Comment: Just updated my answer with a couple more thoughts, since I notice you mentioned you're actually using Ubuntu, despite mentioning a win32 program and asking about a `.scl` directive which seems to mostly be relevant for Windows COFF executables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When learning assembly, you can **mostly focus on the *instructions***, and `.section` and `.globl` directives. Unless you're trying to learn how GAS directives produce metadata, including debug info and other stuff that's useful for debugging high-level languages moreso than hand-written asm.

A lot of debug-info directives like apparently `.scl` only have their syntax documented, no real details on what the values mean or what other things might care about what value you put there.

**You can write working hand-written asm to play around with using pretty much only `.section` and `.globl`**. (And for static data, `.byte` / `.short` / `.long` / `.quad` and `.ascii` / `.asciz` for initialized, `.space` in the BSS, and `.p2align` if you need it).

That's why Matt Godbolt's "compiler explorer" site filters out directives by default, except for data initializers, because of course data is in `.data` or `.rdata`, and code in `.text`, and the interesting part about compiler asm output is the actual instructions (and static data).  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

---

Being fully compliant with Windows expectations for SEH metadata for stack unwinding (especially in 64-bit code) may take some extra directives, same for x86-64 SysV `.cfi` stack-unwind metadata.  But that's something you can worry about *after* you understand the basics of assembly, if you ever need to use hand-written asm in a robust production-quality context, rather than just as a one-off experiment to learn how instructions work.

---

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has some links to tutorials (and manuals), and [Programming from the Ground Up](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/) is a good free book for 32-bit x86 with AT&T syntax. (And GAS directives). It's aimed at running on Linux, so it can teach some OS / computing concepts along the way, the kind of background knowledge necessary for assembly (and system calls) to make sense.  Online HTML [version](https://programminggroundup.blogspot.com/2007/01/chapter-1-introduction.html)

To follow it on a modern 64-bit GNU/Linux distro, you may need `as --32` and `ld -m elf_i386` to override the defaults to 32-bit.  And `gcc -m32 -fno-pie -no-pie` anywhere the book says `gcc`.

You might also want `-fno-stack-protector` to further simplify the asm output from C, if you're comparing book examples of how C compiles.  But be aware that different GCC versions will compile differently, especially as default tuning options have changed over the years.  `-mtune=pentium` or `-mtune=pentium3` might also get GCC to choose code-gen strategies that are more like an old book.  Of course, current GCC's choices are also correct, and more appropriate for newer CPUs, just different from old GCC!

Also the i386 SysV ABI as used on Linux has changed to require 16-byte stack alignment before a `call` instruction, due to GCC accidentally making 32-bit code e.g. using `movaps` that relied on that performance optimization GCC was choosing to do.  Calling libc functions will usually still happen to work in 32-bit code with only 4-byte stack alignment, but if you see modern GCC reserving more space than it needs, that's usually why.

---

Nitpick:

> I found some of assemblers, like NASM, MASM, and GAS. Their syntax is different(particularly pseudo-directives), NASM and MASM support Intel syntax, GAS support AT&T Syntax.

Directives are orthogonal to instruction syntax, and there are different flavours of Intel syntax, especially between MASM vs. NASM.  (As well as major differences between MASM and NASM for directives).

Also, GAS also supports `.intel_syntax noprefix` to use a somewhat MASM-like instruction syntax, but still GAS directives.

(Similarly, YASM has an AT&T mode to use AT&T instruction syntax, but still NASM/YASM preprocessor and directives.)